# Come tradurre threatening meglio che nel dizionario

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, word-choice, translation, single-words

Buongiorno,

Sto cercando di tradurre la parola threatening accuratamente. Le traduzioni che ho trovato sono minaccioso e intimidante.

Tuttavia non sono soddisfatto di queste due traduzioni, perché minaccioso implica un atteggiamento attivo verso porre una minaccia, e anche intimidante, anche se questa sembra più una parola orientata verso imporre rossore, rabbia, magari, non lo so, forse no, anche sottomissione, brividi, ma questo sarebbe più il significato di intimidating. Non penso che la parola intimidante sia orientata verso imporre timidezza. Anche se si può comunicare intimidating, alquanto appositamente, in un modo da infondere un significato, e un senso, di calma. Grazie.

Ma threatening, spesso implica un essere un pericolo per gli altri in un modo in cui la persona che è pericolosa non si rende neanche conto del pericolo che impone, ad una persona.

Questa è una brutta cosa, forse, perché della paura che causa non se ne rende conto, e se ben intenzionato, allora meglio che lo sappia. Così, potrà migliorare, e, si spera, in meglio.

Ma, se, al contrario, questa persona non è ben intenzionata, forse è meglio che rimanga nell'oscurità, e non lo sappia.

Siete d'accordo? Queste sono le considerazioni che sto prendendo in considerazione mentre cerco di tradurre la parola threatening.

Grazie per aver contribuito ad aiutarmi a trovare il giusto pensiero e la parola giusta.

Forse, chi crede di stare nel giusto, può di per sé stesso, creare un senso di minaccia. Ma, come un bambino o una bambina all'asilo, che si appoggia verso un maestro o verso una maestra, da qualche parte bisogna pur stare. Quale, non si sa. (Alcuni bambini potrebbero anche, tra l'altro, avere le loro idee. Penso, che, magari, questi, non andrebbero sempre ignorati).

Grazie.

Comment: Personalmente non vedo tutte queste sfumature di significato. Per me *minaccioso* è un'eccellente traduzione di *threatening*, con il caveat che ovviamente in ogni caso la traduzione giusta dipende dal contesto.

Comment: Contesto, difatti. Purtroppo a questa domanda non è facile rispondere se non aggiungi una frase di esempio, possibilmente con tutto il paragrafo per chiarire meglio.

Comment: Confesso di non aver capito buona parte della domanda. In particolare, non ho capito il fatto dei bambini dell'asilo. Sono loro a essere _threatening_? Sarebbe più utile riportare parte del testo inglese da tradurre, chiarendo in quel caso specifico qual è il problema.

Comment: Da un dizionario Oxford, a proposito di _threatening_: “having a hostile or deliberately frightening quality or manner”. Sottolineo il “deliberately”, il che esclude la situazione in cui “la persona che è pericolosa non si rende neanche conto del pericolo che impone”. Bisogna però dire che una delle altre accezioni è “causing someone to feel vulnerable or at risk”, e forse è a questo che si riferisce l'OP, se intuisco cosa intende.

Answer (score 5):

Difficile rispondere senza contesto.

Anche secondo me **minaccioso** è un'ottima traduzione di *threatening*. Se penso a "un uomo minaccioso", è probabile che stia cercando volontariamente di apparire tale, ma non scontato; potrebbe anche esserlo inconsapevolmente. [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/minaccioso/) riporta, dopo la definizione letterale di "che esprime minaccia":

> Fig., che incute paura per i danni che può provocare o perché costituisce un pericolo: *flutti m.; un m. temporale;* o in genere, che ispira un senso di timore: *nubi m.; tuoni minacciosi*.

Che mi sembra poter esprimere anche una minaccia inconsapevole.

Un'alternativa è **intimorente**.

Quanto a **intimid*e*nte** (e non *intimid**a**nte) questo non vuol dire solo "che incute timidezza" ma anche "che incute timore" - vedi [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/intimidire/).

Occhio che in generale i participi presenti in italiano non hanno proprio lo stesso uso come aggettivi delle forme in *-ing* in inglese: *a threatening man* suona a me molto piú naturale di "un uomo intimorente/intimidente".

Comment: Concordo, in particolare sul fatto che eventuali alternative a “minaccioso” sono molto più forzate e insolite di quanto sia _threatening_ in inglese. Per curiosità, il Ragazzini dà “minaccioso, minatorio”. Chissà da dov'è spuntato quell'*“intimidante”.

Comment: In spagnolo il verbo è *intimidar* quindi il participio presente è proprio *intimidante*. Forse da lí.

Comment: Già, può darsi. Ora che ci penso, in alcuni contesti può essere utile anche “intimidatorio”.